# C program - Print new line before sync byte when is detected

Tags: c

I would like to ask for little help.

I wrote my little program for copy bytes from file, but save it as text.
This is what I got now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf ("Opening input.txt:\n");
    
    FILE *fi;
    fi = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
    
    FILE *fo;
    fo = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    
    if (fo == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    int c;
    
    while((c=fgetc(fi))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("%02X", c & 0xFF);
        fprintf(fo, "%02X", c & 0xFF);
    }
    
    printf("\n\n--- End of file ---\n");
    fprintf(fo, "\n\n--- End of file ---\n");
    
    fclose(fi);
    fclose(fo);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Looks like everything is working as I want, but I have only one little request for *log.txt* format.

This is one example of *input.txt* in HEX format:

> 00 83 70 22 00 30 ........ 88 8C FF FF
>
> 00 83 70 22 ........ 88 8C FF FF
>
> 00 83 70 22 00 ........ 88 8C FF FF

Lines have variable lenght.

And it's printed like this:

> 008370220030........888CFFFF00837022........888CFFFF0083702200........888CFFFF
>
> --- End of file ---

Everything works perfect, but only one problem is that I want to print new line when "0083" is detected. Something like this:

> 008370220030........888CFFFF
>
> 00837022........888CFFFF
>
> 0083702200........888CFFFF
>
> --- End of file ---

I don't have much experiences with C language, but this little program works as I want. Only don't know how to specify code to print new line, when sync byte is detected.

Thank you very much for helping !!!

**EDIT!!!
So finally everything is working as I want! Thanks to everyone !!!**

Comment: So you want to append a newline *after* the `88 8C FF FF` byte pattern is seen?

Comment: Yes, but only for this example. `88 8C FF FF` is changing, but yes, I want something like that.

Comment: You could construct a state machine, acting on {EOF,0,\x83}

Comment: I am not really good in C language, but I appreciate your reply! Can you describe it more? Thank you.

Comment: Please don't edit your question adding  a *solution* . The solution is already visible in the answers.

Comment: OK. I am new here, sorry. Edited now

Answer (score 0):

declare:

```
uint16_t detect = 0xffff;
```

and add after the printf

```
detect <<= 8;
detect |= (unsigned)ch & 0xff;

id(detect == 0x0083) printf("\n");
```

Comment: Firstly I want thank you for your reply!! This code do almost what I want. This code co "\n" after "0083" is detected, but I would print "\n" before "0083" is detected. But I appreciate your reply!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Minimalistic state machine:

- if the program *sees* a `\0`, it does not *yet* print it
- but it does *remember* having seen it.
- on the next character, the `\0` still needs to be printed, but (maybe) a `\n` needs to be output first.
- and the next character is always printed.

[the program will fail if two consecutive `\0` characters occur, but that could be fixed with an extra condition]

---

```
int ch,state;

for(state=0;;){
        ch = getc(fi);
        if (ch == EOF) break;
        switch (state) {
        case 0: if(ch == 0) { state++; continue;}
                break;
        case 1: if(ch == 0x83) fputc('\n', fo);
                fprintf(fo,"00");
                state = 0;
                break;
                }
        fprintf(fo, "02X",ch&0xff);
        }
if(state) fprintf(fo,"00");
```

Comment: YES!!! Thank you!!! Looks like it's working as I want. Now I have to learn what this code exactly mean, but everything looks like it's working like a charm. Thanks!!